# Roast beef for the next day

Tags: beef, refrigerator, roast

So I'm cooking roast beef for Xmas Dinner tomorrow but have to do it tonight as I have no time. Once it's reached temperature I have time to take it out and rest it until it reaches the intended temperature of Medium. But then what do I do once it's reached that temperature while resting? Do I just leave it in the foil to cool down? the fear being that it will continue to cook and go tough. Do I try and cool it as quickly as possible so I can get it into the fridge?

Answer (score 2):

There’s no need to take special measures. Beef doesn’t overcook from being left at a given temperature, just from reaching too high a temperature in the first place. You can let it rest for the normal period (10-20 minutes would be fine) and then refrigerate it.